# jQuery .load() method loads content more than once for each element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have page where I show multiple SAME div's. When i click on a seperate link I want to load to those exactly the same div's some content i got from the server via Ajax. The problem occurs when it loads to that one div content that many times as there are divs. So if i have 3 exactly the same divs, and i click to execute the .load() method, it will load 3 times new content into each div. I want to achive to load only once in each element.

The HTML before the .load() method is executed (I have 3 of these div's in one page):

```
<div data-id-like="747" type="submit" class="submit-like">
  <div class="load-here-747">
    <div class="load-ajax-747">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After the .load() method, each of the 3 div's will look like this:

```
<div data-id-like="747" type="submit" class="submit-like">
  <div class="load-here-747">
    <div class="load-ajax-747">2</div>
    <div class="load-ajax-747">2</div>
    <div class="load-ajax-747">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'div.submit-like', function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        let submit_like = $(this).data('id-like');
        let token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        let all = $(`[data-id-like=${submit_like}]`); 
        let url = window.location.pathname;

        $.ajax({
            url: `/tweets/${submit_like}/like`,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'id': submit_like,
                '__token': token
            }
        }).done(function () {

            $(".load-here-" + submit_like).load(`${url}  .load-ajax-${submit_like}`);
            });            
         });            
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As for this section here, you should clear the content of the elements before loading more into them:

```
....
.done(function () {
    $(".load-here-" + submit_like).html(" ");
    // Remove the content first
    $(".load-here-" + submit_like).load(`${url}  .load-ajax-${submit_like}`);
 });
....
```

---

Then you might try Logging the requests and see what exactly is being received:

```
$(".load-here-" + submit_like).load(`${url}  .load-ajax-${submit_like}`, 
function( response, status, xhr ) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(obj.ok);
});
```

The `load` function accepts a second callback function

Comment: Still doesn't help, it loads the same.

Comment: Try using the callback function above, if it's not implemented correctly then you can check the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things, but this works the best. In my opinion it's a bit long. It gets the length of child nodes and then does a for loop to remove all but one.

```
$(".load-here-" + submit_like).load(`${url}  .load-ajax-${submit_like}`, function() {
  let el = $(this).children().length;
  for (i = 0; i < el; i++) {
    $(`.load-ajax-${submit_like}:nth-child(${i})`).remove();
  }
});
```

But I still think there are a bit more effective ways to do this.